# how use decorators in rails4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, decorator

I install gem 'devise' and make scaffold 'User'. I try extend user_controller. I create file 
app/decorators/controllers/users_controller_decorator.rb:

```
UsersController.class_eval do
  after_filter :find_all_blog_posts, :only => [:create]

  protected
    def find_all_blog_posts
      p '-------------------------------'
      binding.pry
    end
end
```

I run application and via browser create new user. but after press 'submit' console is not display '-------------'. This indicates that the function 'find_all_blog_posts' did not work.

Please help extend controller User in rails4.

ps:

controllers/users_controller.rb:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just inherit the devise userscontroller - dont override it! :-)

**users_controller.rb**

```
UsersController < Devise::UsersController

  after_filter :find_all_blog_posts, only: [:create]

  protected
  def find_all_blog_posts
    binding.pry
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users, controllers:  { registrations: "users_controller" }
```

and more readable stuff
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers

Comment: thanks. but my users_controller already now have a class. i update my question, see at 'PS:'-block

Comment: u still need to inherit it. and then jsut put your custom stuff in it